Mongoose and AWS Lambda optimize connection
I built a lambda that reads and writes from a DB. Using Node JS and Mongoose for MongoDB (last versions).
Obviously, after few dozens of triggers, I get errors "unable to connect" or "need to be connected to perform XX".
I would like to be able to share connections between lambda runs so I can trigger a lambda more than 50 times without hitting the issue.
I use a monorepo. My lambda uses a workspace package that is responsible for the persistence layer. In my lambda, I used to call my db like this :
const db = require('@mypackage/persist/app/models')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
        await db.connect()
    const result = doAction()
        db.close()

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Created things : ' + result.length),
    }
    return response
}

async function doAction() {
    //write things in MongoDB
}

My mongoose implementation is basic :
async function connect() {
    
        await db.mongoose
            .connect(db.url, {
                minPoolSize: 20,
                maxPoolSize: 100,
            })
            .then(() => {
                log('Connected !')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                log('Error !')
                process.exit()
            })
    
}

I know the db.close is my problem here.
Did some research and heard about the possibility to share connection between 2 lambda runs, but I'm failing to implement it well, even after sleeping on the documentation. I see the concept, but my implementation isn't good.
Here's what I did in the lambda :
let conn

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const result = doAction()

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Created : ' + result.length),
    }
    return response
}

async function doAction() {
    if (!conn) {
    conn = await db.connect()
    }

    doThingsInMongoDB()

//end
}

Thing here is that as I don't explicitly disconnect or close the connection, my script won't stop until the connection timesout.
I read all official documentations from Mongoose or MongoDB but couldn't find any that mentionned closing or disconnecting in the lambda... but I can't see how it would stop the current run without this ?
If I close it though, the script stops (locally) but I guess I'll have to re-connect for each lambda... not the point.
Any help would be appreciated. I feel like this is a legend at this point.
